# Java/Android - How can I make a toggle button change state by pressing another button?

Tags: java, android, button, toggle, state

I'm new to developing android apps and I would like to know if it is possible to change the state of a toggle button by pressing another button within the app?

NOTE: This has now been solved, very easy solution:

```
Button setAButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetA);
final ToggleButton mytbSA = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleBtnZoneA);
setAButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     setzoneA();
     mytbSA.setChecked(true);

  } 
   });
```

Comment: Call the toggle button's [`setChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) method? Never programmed with Android, and it took me 5 seconds to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This  [widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) should have a setChecked method:

```
void    setChecked(boolean checked)
```

So if you want to make the toggle button pressed, just call the method on it.

```
ToggleButton mytb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.mytogglebutton);
mytb.setChecked(true); // this will check it
```

In this example the id of the toggle button is 'mytogglebutton', and it will be set to checked.

Answer (score 3):

Set the OnClickListener for the button you want to click. Inside the listener toggleButton.setChecked(bool);

```
buttonIClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIClick);
buttonToToggle= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonToToggle);
buttonIClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
      buttonToToggle.toggle();
  }    
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this error The method isChecked() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: If you are using a toggle button use .toggle().
I have updated my answer.